# Scikit Learn installed error on Python 3.11, 32 bits

Tags: scikit-learn

I have problem while installing Scikit-learn on Python 3.11, 32 bits.

```
(sklearn-venv) C:\Users\212552727>pip install -U scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Obtaining dependency information for setuptools from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/ab/0bcfebdfc3bfa8554b2b2c97a555569c4c1ebc74ea288741ea8326c51906/setuptools-68.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached setuptools-68.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Obtaining dependency information for wheel from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/f5/6955d7b3a5d71ce6bac104f9cf98c1b0513ad656cdaca8ea7d579196f771/wheel-0.41.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached wheel-0.41.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.29.33
        Obtaining dependency information for Cython>=0.29.33 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/a8/be1d37323992bf6e2bece09150ce8f8905216d1df8b70d459df6e2a79c5f/Cython-3.0.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl.metadata
        Using cached Cython-3.0.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
        Obtaining dependency information for oldest-supported-numpy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/9a/756fef9346e5ca2289cb70d73990b4c9f25446a885c1186cfb93a85e7da0/oldest_supported_numpy-2023.8.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
        Using cached oldest_supported_numpy-2023.8.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.5 kB)
      Collecting scipy>=1.5.0
        Using cached scipy-1.11.2.tar.gz (56.0 MB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Installing backend dependencies: started
        Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [21 lines of output]
        + meson setup C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74 C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74\.mesonpy-361i6tyw\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74\.mesonpy-361i6tyw\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
        The Meson build system
        Version: 1.2.1
        Source dir: C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74
        Build dir: C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74\.mesonpy-361i6tyw\build
        Build type: native build
        Project name: SciPy
        Project version: 1.11.2
        WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

        ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
        The following exception(s) were encountered:
        Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
        Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

        A full log can be found at C:\Users\212552727\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h64wkdxq\scipy_1a636eae7acb424b8b57aad910729f74\.mesonpy-361i6tyw\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Have you read the error message and verified that the files are present, e.g. `Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
`

Comment: Why are you using a 32 bit python?

Comment: I am only allowed to use 32 bits.

Answer (score 2):

There are no binary whl packages for the latest scikit-learn for win32 and python3.10. In fact, the latest versions that still has win32 support seems to be [1.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/1.1.2/#files), but only for python 3.9

I would suggest you downgrade to e.g. python 3.9 or something lower.

And then do `pip install --only-binary :all: scikit-learn`.

Alternatively, use `conda` and then create an env with

```
conda create -n scikit python scikit-learn
```

and let it decide on its own what the most recent version of python and scikit-learn is that goes together